# SQL Insert syntax with max(value)+1

Tags: oracle, logic, sql-insert

Using Oracle DB
Trying to create logic where when inserting a new row the logic checks if there is an existing numerical value. If there is a value then the logic would perform a max(value)+1. If there is no value then INSERT '1'.

Comment: Why would you do this rather than using a sequence?  You know this doesn't work in a multiuser environment, right?  What have you tried?  What problem(s) did you encounter?  Are you trying to do this in a procedure?  A trigger?  Something else?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest that you use a sequence instead of looking for the max value + 1.

A sequence would take care of the incrementing for you.  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm

Example:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_SEQ START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Insert like

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, WIDGET) VALUES (NEXTVAL FOR MY_SEQ, 'asdf');
```

Comment: making use of the sequence option can most effectively be accompanied by the implementation of a trigger                                                                                                       `create or replace trigger bi_test
 before insert on my_table

 for each row

 begin

  :new.id := my_seq.nextval;
 
 end`;